# Is it possible to access the shadow dom of an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Here is an svg with a use element:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

In the inspector I can see that the use element has a shadow root:

```
<use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue">
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"></circle>
</use>
```

Is it possible to somehow call methods such as `getBBox()` on the `<circle>` in the shadow dom?

If there is no straight-forward way, maybe there is some trick to allow me to access the closed shadow root?

Comment: try this `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].children[1].getBBox()` and get the BBox of the use tag `{x: 11, y: 1, width: 8, height: 8}`

Comment: @Omer: Maybe my example wasn't the best. I don't want the bbox of the use element. I want the bbox of the circle inside the use element. In my example the values are the same. But a use element can have several graphical elements inside its shadow dom in which case the values would not be the same.

Comment: can you put several elements in use tag?

Comment: In Firefox you can right click the `#shadow-root (closed)` then select `Use in console`. This way you can access the node or other nodes inside of it (animations in my case) `temp0.querySelectorAll("animtaion")[0].beginElement()`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like **no**:

> If you attach a shadow root to a custom element with `mode: closed` set, you won't be able to access the shadow DOM from the outside — `myCustomElem.shadowRoot` returns `null`. This is the case with *built in* elements that contain shadow DOMs, such as `<video>` [or svg].

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM#Basic_usage

Since the web inspector is listing the shadow root as closed, it isn't accessible via javascript.